# Updating Subdomain to Windows Azure Website

Tags: https, website, azure

I have a website that a developer on my team has migrated to Windows Azure. The site represents a subdomain accessible at sub.mydomain.com. To configuration this, I had an 'A' host record pointing at the IP address of the site.

The developer is using a free windows azure web site. From my understanding, web sites on azure are dynamic, so they do not have a static IP address. But they do have a constant mysite.azurewebsites.net address. I'm not sure how to get my https address moved over to Azure. Specifically:

1. How do I point sub.mydomain.com to my mysite.azurewebsites.net
2. When a user visits sub.mydomain.com will they see sub.mydomain.com
   or mysite.azurewebsites.net in the address bar?
3. How do I migratethe https certificate to work with with Azure website?

Thank you so much for your help! I'm super confused at this point.

Comment: You need a CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure CNAME for free windows azure websites, you can do that for shared or reserved websites.

Here is how you would do that after you upgrade your site from free to shared or reserved:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/